# Am I screwed with a Computer Science degree?

Tags: computer-science, job, degree

I'm in my second year of University in Computer Science for a Bsc and I'm getting very scared for the following reason : all jobs I'm interested in seem to ask for a Software Engineers!

I'm starting to worry I didn't make the right choice in chosing CompSci...

Should I try to switch for Software Engineer?

I have a 3 year Technical DEC (Diplôme étude collégial = Collegial Study Diploma (Quebec CEGEP diploma)) in Applied Computer Sciences and have done some side projects...

Could this help me land a software engineer job even if I only have a Bsc In Computer Science and not a Software Engineer degree?

Will I have to redo all my courses even if some are almost the same?

I'm not even sure I understand the difference between the two programs to be quite honest...

Thanks for helping.

Comment: I'm not sure we can answer this question as there are too many individual considerations here.

Comment: (Also, questions arbout undergraduate study are out of the scope of this site. See the [help/on-topic] for details.)

Comment: Stop worrying.  I did a degree in Electronic Physics, and that didn't stop me doing software engineering.  My brother did *Chemistry*.  Software Engineer is a job title, not a qualification.

Comment: Silly question, there is such an abundance of opportunities with you degree. I strongly advise seeing a career adviser that can show you the list of jobs and salaries you can have with your degree.

Answer (score 3):

1. No you're not screwed. Job titles != university majors. CS is just about the best prep for a software engineering position.
2. Generally, you'll land (or not land) a job based on your ability to do it. It also helps to have people who can vouch for your work ethic and technical ability. Stay the course, work hard, and produce visible, positive results and you shouldn't have any trouble finding software engineering positions with your CS degree.

Answer (score 3):

Issue is many universities call software engineering courses Computer Science, 
Or Applied Computer science (Even more so). 
If your course has  more units on Java, or Python, or whatever programming language, than it does on Math and Proofs; then your course is probably actually software engineering.

Your university may offer another course called Software Engineering, 
which also would be on software engineering, but it may be at a master level.
And/Or it may also include extra units on project management.
It will likely be a better course in someways because of that.
But it may have less actual programming, so be worse in others.

In the end though, having a degree doesn't make you a software engineer.
Your degree gets your foot in the door for your first job.
it may even teach you a few useful things.
But once you have a year or so as a full time software dev,
that is what people are going to care about. 
That is going to get you more jobs than your degree.

There are still plenty of self-taught software devs in the world.